# Organizing code in separate Projects vs separate Namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

I work in a .net c# application which contains 2 solutions for client and server. In server side there are 80+ projects that have been used to separate following Architectural layers,

- Infrastructure Layer
- Integration Layer (External Systems)
- Domain Layer
- Repository Layer
- Manager Layer
- Service Layer

In addition, almost every layer has test project.Now, the build time of the solution takes 2 to 3 minutes, and many developers (including me :)) feel we need to tackle this problem.

Therefore,proposed solution was to reduce the number of projects by merging the projects.In my view, it is probably a good solution to minimize the build time and we could achieve what we want.

Proposed solution is that we merge our projects into 3 areas, such as one library for production code, one library for test code, and one for deployment projects (WCF host ,etc) and logically divided layers in same project by separating the namespaces.

However, my concerns are

1. Could these separation good for the maintainability ? providing that more that hundread of classes for each namespace appox.
2. If we have common functionality such as helpers, where are we put those ?

Is there any other way to layering the solution ?

Comment: I'm not sure that making less project will make things build faster, the amount of code will be the same. I don't think VS waste much time on assembling projects.

Comment: Why not rather split your solution into several ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you should split your solutions in logical layers.

As part of where do you put the helpers. Make a solution for it, on one of the lowest levels.

**EXAMPLE**

Software for a farm. You'll need to keep track of your animals, vegetables. You need a module for feeding the animals and one for Selling the animals and vegetables to the consumer market.

This could be splitted in a the following solutions

**Back-end**

- Sell Module: Everyting for selling your products
- Buy Module: Buying seeds, food for your animals, other products, ...
- Sheduler Module: Trigger events for sow seeds, harvesting, ...
- Prediction Module: Predicting harvests quantity's by the weather, and market prices, ...
- ...

Each of these back-end modules, can have it's own Data Access Layer, DTO, WCF Services, ...

This solution will only contain Business Logic, Data Access, ... . And there can be multiple front-end solution connecting to these back-end solutions.

**Front-end**

- ASP.NET MVC Application: Webshop for selling to a consumer
- WPF Application: Approving sells
- Other WPF Application: Buying things.
- Mobile application: Getting the events to your phone or something.
- (Another option is to connect 2 or more backend solutions into 1 front-end solution)
- ...

This is a BIG change for your project and this will have an impact. Make sure you think this true, if you wan't to change it.

Multiple solutions will INCREASE your overall Build Time and it's important to have a nightly build so every developer can always work on the latest binaries, without having to build all the solutions on his local machine.

Note you can still use your layers in the different solutions:

- Infrastructure Layer
- Integration Layer (External Systems)
- Domain Layer
- Repository Layer
- Manager Layer
- Service Layer

---

To make this work all together and don't get messed up with binaries. You can map a drive I.E. X: where you have a folder binaries, where you have a folder for each solution. where each solutions copy's the assemblies on the post build event. (Script this, so it works on every machine)

If you have a good network infrastucture, you can also copy it on a server. So when you build all solutions for example in TFS, it can copy it to a location all developers can access.

If you build in TFS make sure your build order is correct, first the lowest layer, last the highest layer.

But as you split up your solution, in solutions you'll probably don't need them in every solution.

I recently read an article about [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), maybe you can have a look at that too. (It's specific for ASP.NET MVC).

You can also have a look into [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Answer (score 4):

Why 80+ projects while you only have 6 layers in your application ?

You might answer that they cover a large number of functional areas, but do you need all these functional areas in one solution in the first place ?

I'd recommend reflecting *architectural* divisions with projects and *functional* divisions with solutions. Different solutions can reuse the same projects. This way you'll have one project for each reusable architectural layer and as many Domain projects as there are functional areas.

Comment: yup.. good point. we have data contracts, operation contracts in separate projects for many layers. however, we have many external systems projects in the solution too, and now I believe we should remove them from the solution, if applicable

Answer (score 2):

I definitely wouldn't merge the projects... I think you'll quickly end up with spaghetti code in each layer as the developers take shortcuts (whether they mean to or not) that they shouldn't be taking.

I'd be more inclined to separate the layers out into separate solutions... and use binary references instead of project references across the tiers.  This can play havoc with branching though, be careful.

I've seen build times drop by making the projects build to a common place - apparently this can prevent VS rebuilding projects when it doesn't need to - but I don't know if this is true or not.

Some ideas here: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2011/05/17/speed-up-visual-studio-builds.aspx

Finally.... is the three minutes for a full build or just to unit test one project? Focus on whichever is the biggest issue.  If unit testing is taking a long time, you've got a problem with dependencies.  If the full solution is taking a long time, get a build server and focus on bringing your unit test development time down.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

A low impact way I've dealt with a problem like that in the past is to create a series of solution files that include just one of the projects and its test project (and perhaps the project's dependencies).  Then, get yourself a tool like [NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) and do most of your coding in these solutions, probably using TDD.  This will give you lightning fast feedback loops and is decidedly in the spirit of the layered, decoupled approach.  When I've done this in the past, I find that I only actually run the entire application a few times a day, max, and I rely heavily on red-green-refactor, which is nice anyway.

If you want, you don't even have to source control these little solution files -- developers can create their own and they can be borderline throw-away.

Of course, this is by no means a panacea and won't address the problem of long compile times when you want to run the application, but it can definitely help simultaneously cut down on feedback time while promoting good design/development practice and it has the advantage of being extremely low risk and fast to setup.

Comment: Cool. You have remembered me that one of the previous projects which we had done the same thing.Each developer had their own solution file and they keep it for local. However, we experienced a lot of build failures due to conflicts other projects.